# Delete user records from more than one table ASP.Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to delete a record from two tables (Asp.netUser table - holds all the registration details & Checking Account Tables - holds all users details). The delete action method allows the deletion process only on the checking Accounts table. what query / code should i write to delete a record from all the tables?

Delete Action Method

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)

                return HttpNotFound();
                var del = db.checkAccounuts.Find(id);

            if (del == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            db.checkAccounuts.Remove(del);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("ViewAccounts");

        }
```

Records can be deleted from this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CheckingAccount] (
    [Id]            INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountNumber] VARCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]     NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [LastName]      NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [Balance]       DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [AppUserId]     NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [User_Id]       NVARCHAR (128)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.CheckingAccounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.CheckingAccounts_dbo.AspNetUsers_User_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([User_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
);
```

But the user details remain in this table!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT            NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT            NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc]    DATETIME       NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Pin]                  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([UserName] ASC);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to find user details via checking account object and then delete it , modified method will look like

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    var del = db.checkAccounuts.Find(id);

    if (del == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    aspnetusers user = db.aspnetusers.find(del.User_Id);

    db.checkAccounuts.Remove(del);
    db.aspnetusers.remove(user.ID);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("ViewAccounts");
}
```

In case you want to perform deletion from backend, you can use SQL table trigger to delete data in user table based on deletion of records from checking table or you can also use a stored procedure to delete records from both tables, just call the stored procedure from your code.